# How to update all data representing an SVG line using d3?

Tags: javascript, json, svg, d3.js

I used this code as my starting point: https://github.com/lucasfilippi/d3-radar

My JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/gingerbeardman/Cdg58/

Here's a sample radar chart that it draws:

[image: Sample radar chart ourput]

The original binds data using an external JSON file, but I prefer to bind a dynamically generated JSON object. I randomly generate some data for the purposes of this proof-of-conept demo.

However, I'm stuck with how to get the chart to show the new/updated data.

```
function refresh() {
  var data = rndData();

  d3.select("#container")
    .datum(data)
    .call(chart);
}

function rndData() {
  var newData = [...];

  return newData;
}
```

I have set up a function on click event to draw a new chart with random data, but there is no visual change when it is called. I've verified that the data is different and that the call happens.

The code does not use the update() and exit() calls, perhaps that's not so bad given no points on the line are actually being added or removed. I simply want each point on the SVG line to transition to new co-ordinates.

Comment: You must bind the new data and call the chart component again.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how I am binding the new data and calling the chart again.

Comment: After having a quick look at the code it seems like the update/exit selections aren't handled at all. That is, you can't update with this implementation, just draw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way the current code is set up is not really compatible with being able to update. To do this, quite substantial changes have to be made.

The first problem is that the code only operates on new SVGs. Everything happens on `gEnter`, which is an empty selection if the SVG is there already. This is easy enough to fix though by reselecting the `g` element after appending it and then operating on that. This will select both newly-appended `g`s and those that were there before.

```
 var g = svg.select("g");
```

Furthermore, the way appending elements is done throughout the code usually looks like this:

```
var something = foo.selectAll(".bar").data(data).enter().append();
```

This only handles the enter selection and doesn't even allow access to the other selections. Refactoring this to look like

```
var something = foo.selectAll(".bar").data(data);
something.enter().append();
something... // change update selection
```

fixes the problem.

Complete, working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cdg58/7/). Note that I'm not handling the exit selection in there as it is not necessary for this example.

Comment: +1 Great job...I was going to check the rest of the code for issues with the enter/update/exit pattern...but no need now, you got it. In retrospective, I focused too much on one piece of the puzzle...and missed the simplification of selection on the `g`.

Comment: I think that the design of the component is needlessly complicated by the fact that the author wants to support multiple SVGs per selection element. This is the main reason for the issue with the updating...

Comment: Great work, thanks! Especially for the explanation of how things were simplified. I can't award the bounty yet (too early) but this is currently where it will go. Thanks again.

Comment: Bounty awarded. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

The way the original code is setup, the `svg` element is really the pivotal element for the enter/update/exit pattern. Here are some excerpts from the code changes I made:

```
// Select the svg element, if it exists.
var svg = d3.select(this)
    .selectAll('svg')
    .data([metrics]);

// --> svg exit selection
svg.exit().remove();

// --> svg enter selection
svg.enter().append('svg');

// create the skeletal chart.
var svgAppend = svg
  .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (side / 2) + ', ' + (side / 2) + ')');

...

// --> svg update selection
svg.selectAll('.radar')
    .each(function (d, n) {
        chart.drawArea(d3.select(this), n);
    })
```

I renamed the `gEnter` variable to `svgAppend` because it more clearly expresses what is happening.

Here is the complete working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hv43n/).

Comment: Ouch...I should have checked that...made a mental note to do it and then my real job was upon me :)...I will look at it again later...but, of course, feel free to come up with your response if you have time. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it looks like you need to pass in your data like this:

```
d3.json("radar.json", function(error, data) { d3.select("#container") .datum(data) .call(chart); });
```

so, I'd place your data object variable in lieu of "radar.json" in the example and just make sure that it is formatted correctly according to the doc.  Did you try that already?

Comment: That's how it was when it was loading from an external JSON file. I removed the outer `d3.json` call and build the `data` object myself. It runs/displays correctly either way, but I can't update with new data either way.